# I'm getting an error when I run this gui in tkinter Python 3.9

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

```
count = 0

def click():
    global count
    count+=1
    print(count)

from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='icon.ico')

button = Button(window,
                text="Click me!",
                command=click,
                font=("Comic Sans",30),
                fg="#00ff00",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="#00ff30",
                activebackground="#0a0a0a",
                state=ACTIVE,
                image=photo,
                compound='bottom')  # ACTIVE, DISABLED
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

error:     self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "icon.ico"

Comment: `tkinter.PhotoImage` can only display images in PGM, PPM, GIF, and PNG formats.

Comment: Alright, I will try a PNG now. Do you know a way for ICO formats?

Comment: I just tried with a png, _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "image.png"

Comment: Maybe try using a `tkinter.BitmapImage` for ICO. Simply renaming the image doesn't convert the image format. You probably just renamed `image.ico` to `image.png`, in which case the image is still an ICO. You need to use a photo editor to convert the ICO format to PNG format.

Comment: This doesn't really relate to the programming question but you might also want to change the font. Comic Sans is way overused and is overall hated.

Comment: It was another photo that I had on my desktop, I used it to test if the png would work, and ive tried:
photo = tkinter.BitmapImage(file='icon.ico')
and it returns format error in bitmap data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Update Python 3.12.0 or later(3.12.0rc3:b973ab3)

It will work on `.ico` format for both `iconbitmap` and widget keyword `image=`

Output, you will see .ico on window title:

[image]